# While drag & drop inner elements overlapping each other

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am D&D list rows. It is working fine functionally but visually I have some issues. I can see inner elements of the row in the list and the length of the row has been changed while I D&D it.

The html is standard:

```
    <table
    formArrayName="products"
    cdkDropList
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <tbody *ngFor="let element of getProducts();let i=index"
      class="border-bottom-color drag-box"
      [formGroupName]="i"
      cdkDrag>
     ......
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that my components are complex and have many inner elements. In angular Material examples the rows are simple and have fixed width.

Comment: Did you fix it? @TuviaKhusid